# UV map center align multiple vertices of two different islands by distance?

Tags: uv, vertices

I'd like to overlap UV map islands which use the exact same textures. Despite coming from almost symmetrical parts of the mesh, their shapes always differ slightly on the UV map so I cannot use scale/rotate/move to overlap them whole with 100% precision.

[image: UV map overlapping islands but misaligned vertices]

My current method is to roughly overlap the islands. Then separately select all vertex pairs between them and then in the UV context menu, align X and then again to align Y. But this is very time consuming. Is there a way to select all vertices and align them based on how close they are to each other ? Similarly to how you can merge vertices of a mesh by distance, but align instead of merging ?

Comment: In UV mode,you can also use cursor to selected, or selected to cursor,as usual. Another way is   snapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no merging risk in the UV Editor, in any case the vertices will share the same location, and that's exactly what you want... you should be able to use the 'merge' M > By Distance operator here, and it will overlap the uv coordinates -but keep them independent-

it works even on different meshes if you shift select them and go edit mode

Answer (score 0):

Solved! UVPackmaster 3 has perfect tool for this: https://uvpackmaster.com/doc3/blender/latest/40-miscellaneous-modes/10-aligning-tools/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/158611)